# run cURL command and save output file to AWS S3 using shell script

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a shell script called **getData.sh** that I use to perform a cURL POST command.

```
$1
$2
date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')

if [[ -n $1 ]] && [[ -n $2 ]] ; then
  curl -4 -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -H "Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxx" \
   -H "X-Async:false" \
   -d \
'{   
  "variables": {    
    "start_ts"    : "2020-11-03 '"${1}"'",
    "end_ts"      : "2020-11-03 '"${2}"'",
    "select_columns" : "*",
    "where": "content is NOT NULL"
  }  
}
' \
 'http://xxxx:8080/app/v1/app/sQuery' > $date-$1-$2.gz

else
  exit 1
```

fi

When i run this... `./getData.sh 13:00:00 14:00:00`

this outputs a file like:

> 2020-12-01-13:00:00-14:00:00.gz

Now I would like to upload this file to S3. I can run a command like this:

aws s3 cp /home/user/2020-12-01-13:00:00-14:00:00.gz s3://my-test-s3-bucket-2020-aws/

It works, **so I would like to know how I can combine this in one script where it automatically runs the aws s3 copy command and copies it over to S3. Tried a few things but it is executed before file cURL is complete so uploads part of the file...**

I tried the following but it does not give me power to upload it with a GIVEN name of the file because it just uploads it with the name "-"

`curl xxx | aws s3 cp - s3://my-test-s3-bucket-2020-aws/`

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but perhaps

```
'http://xxxx:8080/app/v1/app/sQuery' > $date-$1-$2.gz && aws s3 cp $date-$1-$2.gz s3://my-test-s3-bucket-2020-aws/
```

will be helpful

Comment: Is there no way to save it directly - without first saving it locally.

Comment: not that I know of. S3 is a block storage, and technically underneath it is a simple key value store.
You could add

&& rm $date-$1-$2.gz

to the end of the command to remove file directly after upload.